# International conference in United Kingdom for doctors

Tags: visas, uk, conferences

1. I'm attending an international conference about diabetes, which is paid by me and not sponsored. I intend to attend as a listener. I am a general practitioner doctor. What visa should I apply for academic for clinical practice or business to attend a lecture?
2. I'm Sudanese and I live in Saudi Arabia. The application asks:

> What permission do you have to be in Saudi Arabia?
>
> - I have a temporary visa.
> - I am a permanent resident.

I do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident. Although I was born in Saudi Arabia and have always had a residence permit.

Comment: It is confusing: "I have temporary visa", "I'm a permanent resident", "I'm not a permanent resident". It is contradictory, or you left the context (so which country apply what) And if you have a residence permit, why do you have a temporary visa? The details are very important here, else you may get an answer which doesn't fit to your case

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Those are the options on the form, I believe.

Comment: If you "live in Saudi Arabia", in what way are you not "a permanent resident of Saudi Arabia"?

Comment: @Sneftel "Permanent resident" means a specific status typically meaning that someone is entitled to continue living in a country without meeting extra requirements (like work or study). eg, in the US "green card" holders are permanent residents. Many visa holders *live in* the US, sometimes for many years, but don't (yet) hold a green card.

Comment: As @Sneftel stated, it’s the options on the application provided. And yes if you are a foreign even if was born in  Saudi Arabia you won’t be a permanent resident. Permanent residency is more a better version of residency permit as it’s for foreigners who are investing to own properties in Saudi for like 15 M SR. While the residency permit is supposed to be established by a Saudi  sponsor like you employer or father who works to a Saudi sponsor. In my case I’m sponsored by my employer as am already working

Comment: @DaleyaMedani it is best to edit clarifications into your question as people may not read the comments and vote to close this as needing more detail.